# How to display window on another screen using PySimpleGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

So i have a program that uses a few windows using PySimpleGUI. And now, if I'm going to drag my window to different monitor i want the new one to pop up on the screen that i drag the previous window to. i've tried using `.move_to_center()` ,`get_screen_dimensions()` and `.current_location()` but i can't figure it out. Thats my code that i got so far. `current_location` variable is a location of previous window.

```
def correct_location(window, current_location):

screen_size = window.get_screen_dimensions()
print("Screen size: ", screen_size)
x_screen, y_screen = screen_size
print("current location: ", current_location)
x, y = current_location

if x < 0 or y < 0:
    window.move_to_center()
# if x - x_screen < 0:
#     x_screen = abs(x - x_screen)
# if y - y_screen < 0:
#     y_screen = abs(y - y_screen)
# window.move(x_screen, y_screen)
# print(window.current_location())

for monitor in screeninfo.get_monitors():
    print(monitor)
return None
```

the output is following:

```
Screen size:  (1280, 720)
current location:  (-1441, 340)
Monitor(x=-1920, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=527, height_mm=296, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY2', is_primary=False)
Monitor(x=-3840, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=527, height_mm=296, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY3', is_primary=False)
Monitor(x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=309, height_mm=174, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY1', is_primary=True)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The idea behind the code is:
if x or y is negative -> it means it goes to another screen -> center the window. but it keeps going back to primary window center. i think from the data that i got so far it is possible to find out solution but i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This [cookbook recipe](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-positioning-windows-on-a-multi-monitor-setup-tkinter-version-of-pysimplegui-only) may be useful.  Of course, it may not be useful.

Keep coding.  Keep notes.

Have fun.